# Run linux script when mail is received

Tags: linux, email

I'm looking for a way to have a Raspberry Pi receive an mail and run a script after receiving.

I don't find anything related to this online. Any advice? Thanks :)

Comment: Google the `mutt` e-mail client, and set it up. As it is the question is too broad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd set up procmail on that raspi, and add a user account that will receive the coffee status emails and which holds the procmail recipes and your script. See [How to Run a script when a mail arrives in mail server? (Debian)](https://serverfault.com/questions/261191/how-to-run-a-script-when-a-mail-arrives-in-mail-server-debian) for example.